# AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I have no idea how to fix this problem that I get from my Python code when I am using Flask:

```
@app.route('/addEvent/', methods=['POST'])
def addEvent():

@app.route('/deleteEvent/', methods=['POST'])
def addEvent():
```

Error message:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: addEvent
21:50:57 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I tried understanding this page: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/viewdecorators/

Also this post [AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256602/assertionerror-view-function-mapping-is-overwriting-an-existing-endpoint-functi)

But I don't understand. Could someone please tell me how to fix this for my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rename the second function; it too is called `addEvent`; I suggest `deleteEvent` instead:

```
@app.route('/deleteEvent/', methods=['POST'])
def deleteEvent():
```

The *endpoint* name is normally taken from the function you decorated with `@app.route()`; you can also explicitly give your endpoint a different name by telling the decorator what name you'd want to use instead:

```
@app.route('/deleteEvent/', methods=['POST'], endpoint='deleteEvent')
def addEvent():
```

which would let you stick to using the same name for the function. In this specific case, that's *not a good idea*, because one function replaced the other and the only reference left to the first is in the Flask URL map.

Also see the [`Flask.route()` documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.route):

> **endpoint** – the endpoint for the registered URL rule. Flask itself assumes the name of the view function as endpoint.