# Everythings is working fine in flask but when I am adding the following code it's giving error

Tags: python, flask

### Below is my flask code and it's working fine

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/hello")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/test")
def search():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

---

**but when I am adding the this code**

```
@app.route("/test/<search_query>") 
def search(search_query):   
    return search_query
```

**it's giving the following error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 19, in
>   
>       def search(search_query):   File "C:\Users\khadush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1315, in decorator
>       self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)   File "C:\Users\khadush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 98, in wrapper_func
>       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\khadush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1282, in add_url_rule
>       raise AssertionError( AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: search

Comment: Looks like you can’t have 2 functions with the same name “search”

Answer (score 0):

As it is clearly mentioned in the error.

> View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function:
>   search

That means, there is already a function named 'search'. I recommend you to change the function name like :

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('name')

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/hello")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/test")
def search(): return "Hello"

@app.route("/test/")
def search(search_query):  # Duplicate route for /test (hence the error function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint)
    return search_query
```

Please delete the old search function that maps to /test.
Also refer, [AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256602/assertionerror-view-function-mapping-is-overwriting-an-existing-endpoint-functi)

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some bugs thats why it is giving you an error. It is not related to multiple search function as you don't have it. I made the changes below and it worked.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") 

@app.route("/hello")

def hello_world(): 
  return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/test") 
def search(): 
   return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

You can learn about these errors more here:
[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Hope this helps !